# Insert Statement using multiple where clauses

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I'm trying to create a new table where they are based off the same variable. Below is my attempt at getting it to work, I've tried a few other thins as well.

I have to create a table where x and x1 are side by side. When I try to insert individually, I get a table that looks like

x  | null

x  | null

null | x1

null | x1

I want a table that results in

x      |  x1

x  | x1

```
insert into inter 
(
x, 
x1
)

select

unrolled.`Sum of New Lds` from unrolled where pastdate(`Week end`)='2014-06-08',

(select unrolled.`Sum of New Lds` from unrolled where `Week end`='2014-06-08')
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (ColumnX1, ColumnX2) VALUES ('x1', 'x2')
```

If you need to do it in 2 separate statements for some reason, you cant insert into an existing row, for that you want update, something like

```
UPDATE TableName SET ColumnX2='X2' WHERE ColumnX1 = 'x1'
```

Comment: Yes. It doesnt matter where the values come from really.